# Cannot start application: grails 3 + tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails3.2.0

I'm trying to deploy and run my app on tomcat8,
deployment seems ok, but when I'm accessing app:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /app/

type Status report

message /app/

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 (Debian)
```

Catalina.out:

```
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/app.war has finished in 11,475 ms
..
INFO: Server startup in 14676 ms
```

Please suggest, how to debug such behavior

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency to be `provided` and comment out `groovy-ant` dependency.

Please check [this](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10208) out.